# How can I connect my A500 to an iMac for charging and file transfers?

Tags: usb, charging, macos, acer-iconia-a500

I have a Acer Iconia A500 and I am using an iMac. I cannot charge or share my device as mass storage with my computer over USB, though I am able to use bluetooth for transferring data.

Are there any special drivers needed? How can I get it connected with my machine?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the mass storage issue, but I don't believe it's designed to charge via USB. A lot of tablets aren't.

Comment: But my friend owned the same A500, he said his tab is getting charged via USB in his windows machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As eldarerathis mentioned, you need to charge the tablet using the charging adapter rather than USB.

The A500 has 2 USB ports.  A regular one, like you'd find on a laptop, for connecting USB devices **to** the tablet (memory sticks, for example), and a Micro USB port for connecting the tablet to a computer.  Make sure you're using the **Micro USB** port.

(Your mileage may still vary - the support site isn't very forthcoming on using the tablet with a Mac)

Comment: Motorola Xoom also does not charge via USB. It charges via power adapter that came with the device.